# Creating an executable file with cx_Freeze. How do I allow user input?

Tags: python, input, exe, cx-freeze

Really struggling to get a user input when I run an exe file created by cx_Freeze. If I create a script that requires no input, it runs fine. A black window appears for a second then disappears, and script runs in the background.

The problem is, if user input is required there is no console window to type in

My setup script looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup( name = "SpecialApp",

       version= "0.1",
       description="Performs useful things",
       executables = [Executable("specialapp.py")])
```

I've tried Base="Console" and Base="Win32GUI" but neither make a difference.

Another thing, this may need its own question, but does anyone know how to run the Exe file without requiring the .dll files to be present? I don't want to give my end users a huge folder full of files, I'd like to give them just the exe file or a bat file if possible.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try adding `base = Win32GUI` in `executables = [Executable("specialapp.py")])` so it looks like:

```
[Executable("specialapp.py",base = None)])
```

Note that `Win32GUI` **hides** the console.

If that still does not work try running from command prompt (or your OS equivalent) and see if there are any error messages (just because it compiles and starts without errors it does not mean there are any).

2) For single file exe I suggest you go for [Pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or build into an installer with `bdist_msi` command you could also try IExpress.

3)  The DLLs provide the Python runtime libraries so realistically no not with Cx_Freeze.

Hope I helped

Comment: Thanks Simon. It still doesn't work. Will attempt using command prompt and see what the error is. Unfortunately I'm using winpython and am not allowed to install anything else, so it seems that cx_freeze is the only option at the moment! I guess I could save the folder somewhere with all dll files and then provide batch scripts to the end users to run?

Comment: @Actuary  Yes I please tell us what the error message is.  And I can also help with the batch part as well.

Comment: I get the error message: cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll when trying to run in cmd prompt

Comment: @Actuary.  Just try copying mkl_intel_thread.dll into the build folder and see if it works. If it does not I'll get another solution typed up.

Comment: @Actuary  `@echo off`, `python file.py`.  Copy the Python installation with all the necessary folders and place the script above along with python.exe and you script.  It will now launch from the Python interpreter.

Comment: That's the batch script solution.  I'll see what I can do about the missing Dll later.

Comment: But will this work if the end user does not have python installed?

Comment: @Actuary  To find out try this simple test:  rename your entire python installation so it cannot be found in PATH.  Run the bat file and see if it works.